# Why is this not rendering my mapping? Is the import made correctly?

Tags: reactjs, moralis

Here is the code for Moralis that I'm trying to render only if the username matches the username:

```
function Redpit() {
    const { authenticate, isAuthenticated, user } = useMoralis();
    const [isActivated, setisActivated] = useState(false);
    const { Moralis, isInitialized } = useMoralis();
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useMoralisQuery("Posts");

    const results = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
    const finalResult = JSON.parse(results)

    const createPost = () => {
        setisActivated(true);
    }

    useEffect(async () => {
        const query = await new Moralis.Query("Posts");
        const posts = query.find();
    }, [])

return(

                                <div class="pit-post">

                                    <figure>

                                        <span><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></span>

                                        <i class="fa fa-image"></i>

                                    </figure>

                                        {finalResult.map((result) => {

                                            {user.get("username") === result.author.username ? <Userpost /> : void(0)}                                  
                                        })}

)
}
```

This is the code I’m trying to render:

```
import { useMoralis, useMoralisQuery } from "react-moralis";

function Userpost() {

    const { data, error, isLoading } = useMoralisQuery("Posts");

    const results = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)

    const finalResult = JSON.parse(results)

    return (

        <div>

            {finalResult.map((result) => {

                                            return <div class="central-meta item">

                                            <div class="pit-post">

                                                <figure>

                                                    <img src="images/resources/red-post2.jpg" alt="" />

                                                    <i class="fa fa-video"></i>

                                                </figure>

                                                <div class="pit-post-deta">

                                                    <h4><a href="social-post-detail.html" title="">{result.title}</a></h4>
</div>
                                        })}

        </div>

    )

}

export default Userpost
```

I’m trying to render a component only if the user matches the current user, but it is not rendering as expected, because it renders nothing. There is no error in the code, it just renders nothing.

Comment: You're missing the `return` statement in your map in `Redpit`

Comment: Agreed. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: @WebbH where should the return be put in?

Comment: `return {user.get("username") === ...`